# workflow solution for upload and show feature

Tags: php

I have a lists of html select boxes say 30. I need to give a option for a user to browse a file, where he would have stored the values of these select boxes. once he selects a file, i need to show the value in corresponding select boxes.

1. Do i need to store this file on server and read the file?
2. i have idea to ask to user to store the files in .ini format so that i can parse the file and do it. any other way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file will be stored on the server automatically on POST, although temporarily. You can read the temporary file directly (i.e.: $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']) without having to use move_uploaded_file(). This way you don't have to worry about garbage collection either.

INI works, so does XML.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Sometimes it can be right. You can parse INI file with help of native php function [parse_ini_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php)